# check empty for a lot inputs and get a single alert

Tags: jquery

```
<input type='text' class='inputx'>
<input type='text' class='inputx'>
<input type='text' class='inputx'>
... 20 inputs.
```

I need to check if any of them is empty.

```
$('.inputx').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '') {console.log('empty');}
    });
```

But `empty` is written 20 times !
How can I get only one console writing if any of `inputx` is empty?

Comment: There's a good chance that the *actual* problem would be solved by just adding `required` to all inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with it by using a [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/),

```
var emptyElements = $('.inputx').filter(function(){ 
  return $(this).val() == '') 
});

if(emptyElements.length) console.log("Empty elements found!");
```

Or you could optimize it by using a simple for loop,

```
var elems = $('.inputx')
for(var x = 0; x < elems.length; i++){
 if(elems.get(x).value.length == 0) break;
}

if(--x != elems.length) console.log("Empty elements found!");
```

Comment: Thanks. I think jquery should have a function like `if any inputx empty...`

Comment: @bonaca Yeah. But unfortunately it doesn't have a one like that. Glad to help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try value attr selector

```
    if ($("input:text.inputX[value!='']").length >0) {
     // empty elements found
    }
```

Comment: I think `:empty` will not check for values.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yes. Trying value attr now :)